# Scrape Offer returns no results

Tags: error-handling, html-parsing, web-scraping

I have researched this issue in the database, googled the questions, and found two different errors.  I have determined that the 503 errors are Amazon blocking me but I get a different error that is along the same lines but doesn't have the 503 return in it.  I'm not able to decipher the difference.  Anyone able to help?  The errors I am getting are listed below.  The html parser I am using are HTML Agility Pack and Just Agile

> http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/1902915208 error The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

and

> Scrape Offers returned no results.

The error is not consistent and so not easy to trap. The error returns with in the next scrap.  It is very random and does not happen with the same product consistently.  I am getting lots of these daily and it is preventing me from updating prices and provide correct information to customers.

Comment: I have same problems. I am using CURL and Servers are located in Germany. Have you found any soulution yet?

Answer (score 3):

So as i found out, the problem was the User-Agent which was send to Amazon.
I added the following command to my CURL-options and it works now - even without an US-Proxy.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Answer (score 0):

I put 1 second sleep between every 20 webpage requests. And that solved my problem.